# Initializing and evaluating Matrix in Python

Tags: python-2.7

I was wondering, if someone could explain this behavior in python 
while initializing matrix in python in the following way

```
rows,cols = 3,3
visited = [[False]*rows]*cols
visited[0][0] = True 
print visited
[[True, False, False], [True, False, False], [True, False, False]]
```

As apposed to

```
visited = []
for i in range(rows):
   visited.append([False]*cols)
visited[0][0] = True
print visited
[[True, False, False], [False, False, False], [False, False, False]]
```

I am not sure, why in the first case all the elements of first col gets initialized to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oswald shot the 35th president of the US, and then a certain John Fitzgerald Kennedy died. Why? Because they're the same person.

`[[False]*rows]*cols` will first construct an array `[False, False, False]` - let's call it John - then construct another array that has three Johns in it. Not three copies of John - three references to John.

A simpler demonstration of the same principle:

```
a = [False]
b = a
a[0] = True
b[0]
# => True
```

`b`'s `[False]` is not just a copy of `a`'s `[True]`: there is only one `[True]`, with two names for it (`a` and `b`).

The difference can easily be seen in this visualisation (click "forward" to step through the program):

- [Three Johns](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=john%20%3D%20%5BFalse%5D%20*%203%0Athree_johns%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20i%20in%20range(3%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20three_johns.append(john%29%0Athree_johns%5B1%5D%5B1%5D%20%3D%20True%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

  ```
  john = [False] * 3
  three_johns = []
  for i in range(3):
      three_johns.append(john)
  three_johns[1][1] = True
  ```
- [Three random guys](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=three_random_guys%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0Afor%20i%20in%20range(3%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20three_random_guys.append(%5BFalse%5D%20*%203%29%0Athree_random_guys%5B1%5D%5B1%5D%20%3D%20True%0A&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

  ```
  three_random_guys = []
  for i in range(3):
      random_guy = [False] * 3
      three_random_guys.append(random_guy)
  three_random_guys[1][1] = True
  ```

Thus, the easiest way to initialise a 2D matrix properly is this:

```
[[False] * rows for _ in range(cols)]
```